# Working with Cocos 2d-x inside of Microsoft Visual Studios Community 2015

Tags: c#, ios, cocos2d-x, visual-studio-2015

To start things off i am an amateur programmer and have basically only used visual studios to make anything i have made in school. C# is what i am familiar with as far as game development goes, and at this point i am trying to develop a game using visual studios & cocos2ds. That i can somehow port over to the Apple App Store.(Stop me if any of this is completely impossible, like i said i am quite new to the whole app development thing)

So I have one Big question that kind of stems off into a few others. Most importantly I currently have Microsoft Visual Studios Community 2015 version, and I would like to use Cocos 2d-x in unison with VS to create an app. I have currently sifted through a lot of different websites and eventually stumbled upon this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xqtT0E68TJM. This guy is the most informative resource i have found for installing Cocos with VS. I followed his entire tutorial to the very end. With a few minor changes.

At the very end of the tutorial you can see he opens the project.sln file in Visual Studios and runs it. This then brings up the little interface with some numbers across the bottom. When i open it in my Visual Studios it says :

```
"Unable to start program"

C:\Users\guy\Desktop\Personal\Projects\GameTest1\GameTest1\proj.win32\Debug.win32\GameTest1.exe

The system cannot find file specified."
```

I cant figure out What exactly is going wrong and why mine wont work. Like i said i only changed a few things from the tutorial but that was because it was from years ago, So i had VS 2015 instead of 13 etc. But my changes were as follows:

I updated my Java recently which was up to Java 8. I downloaded the Newest Eclipse from their website and ran it just like in the tutorial ^. But it didn't work so i had to figure out that in order to run .py files like in the tutorial you had to add "python " before the "cocos.py new ......" in order to create a new file. Then it told me that i had to be running Java 1.6 Whilst i was currently running 1.8. So i downloaded an earlier build of Java then used it as the path destination for eclipse. Then aside from that everything built and i ended up with the right files named correctly in the right spot and presumably in the right format. It just gave me that error ^ at the very last step of the tutorial :S.

Comment: This is to wide - do you refer to c#, java, or python?

Comment: I am familiar with C#. However i want to use cocos 2d-x in Visual studios. I am happy to try and learn whatever language is necessary to code an IPhone app. I only referred to Python because i needed it in the installation, And i thought i would give potential readers some background on my situation. The only thing i am really asking for help on is getting the finished product to run in visual studios that was created using the Youtube tutorial ^. My file came up with the error i mentioned and i am trying to figure out why mine came up with an error and his didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - Cocos2d-x uses C++ or Js(i.e. Cocos2d-js) and not C#.
Secondly - Yes you can port your app to apple app store with Cocos2d-x but it can only be done by a mac but not a windows pc .So if you want to port your game to apple devices you must be having a mac.
Thirdly - It doesn't matter if you have installed java unless you are developing for android.If you want to port your game to android then you must have java installed(it doesn't matter if you have latest version or not but you should install greater than v1.5)

Now coming to your problem
Ensure that you have python version2.7 or greater is installed version 3. will not work.
Also ensure that you don't have any spaces in your file path as that may cause error sometimes.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Lovekesh Garg provided me with a complete, if not incredibly extensive (abundantly helpful) explanation of basically everything i have asked.

I have been pursuing other interest after realizing the expense involved after some investigation so i apologize for the late answer posting :S.